# Report - Running Count within a Group

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access 2007 report which is grouped by RoomType_ID

I need to do a running count on each line within the Group so that I end up with something like:

RoomType_ID 1
1  Mr and Mrs Smith
2  Mr and Mrs Jones
3  Mr and Mrs Smythe

RoomType_ID 2
1  Mr Foo
2  Mrs Bar

etc...

How can I go about getting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place a text box in the details section of the report, make the data source of the text box simply:

=(1)

On the data tab of the above text box, set the running sum = “over all”

So, you  have For one line of detail in the report:

```
[=(1)] [Couples Name] [Phone Number] ..etc
```

And, I would call the text box "textCount"

And, if you want at the “end” of the report, you can show a final count by placing the above text name in another text box in the reports FOOTER. 
eg:
    [textCount]

Set the running sum to no.

Comment: Thanks Albert. I used this method, except setting the running sum = "over group" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If probably use (detail) sections in your report (for the grouping). You can make a global integer for the running total value and have it reset every time the 'on layout' or 'on print' event of the header section fires.