# MS Access: Rank SUM() Values

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am working on an old web app that is still using MS Access as it's data source and I have ran into issue while trying to rank SUM() values.

Let's say I have 2 different account numbers each of those account numbers has an unknown number of invoices. I need to sum up the total of all the invoices, group it by account number then add a rank (1-2).

RAW TABLE EXAMPLE...

Account | Sales | Invoice Number
001     | 400   | 123
002     | 150   | 456
001     | 300   | 789

DESIRED RESULTS...

Account | Sales | Rank
001     | 700   | 1
002     | 150   | 2

I tried...

SELECT Account, SUM(Sales) AS Sales,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Invoices) AS RANK
FROM Invoices
ORDER BY Account

But that query keeps returning the number of records assigned to that account and not a rank.

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier in a report, with a running count: [Report - Running Count within a Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062648/report-running-count-within-a-group)

This is not standard in a query, but you can do something with custom functions (it's elaborate, but possible):
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/94397/en-us

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to break it up in to 2 queries, the first one is this and I've saved it as **qryInvoices**:

```
SELECT Invoices.Account, Sum(Invoices.Sales) AS Sales
FROM Invoices
GROUP BY Invoices.Account;
```

And then the second query uses the first as follows:

```
SELECT qryInvoices.Account, qryInvoices.Sales, (SELECT Count(*) FROM qryInvoices AS I WHERE I.Sales > qryInvoices.Sales)+1 AS Rank
FROM qryInvoices
ORDER BY qryInvoices.Sales DESC;
```

I've tested this and got the desired results as outlined in the question.

Note: It may be possible to achieve in one query using a **Defined** table, but in this instance it was looking a little ugly.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the answer in one query, it should be

```
SELECT inv.*, ( 
    SELECT 1+COUNT(*) FROM (
        SELECT Account, Sum(Sales) AS Sum_sales FROM Invoices GROUP BY Account
    ) WHERE Sum_sales > inv.Sum_sales
) AS Rank
FROM (
    SELECT Account, Sum(Sales) AS Sum_sales  FROM Invoices GROUP BY Account
) inv
```

I have tried it on Access and it works. You may also use different names for the two instances of "Sum_sales" above to avoid confusion (in which case you can drop the "inv." prefix).